# Simplest way to define a type that is a sequence of a specific number of elements in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I'm doing something like the following:

```
val a = complicatedChainOfSteps("c")
val b = complicatedChainOfSteps("d")
```

I'm interested in writing code like the following (to reduce code and copy/paste errors):

```
val Seq(a, b) = Seq("c", "d").map(complicatedChainOfSteps(_))
```

but having the compiler ensure that the number of elements matches, so the following don't compile:

```
val Seq(a, b) = Seq("c", "d", "e").map(s => s + s)
val Seq(a, b) = Seq("c").map(s => s + s)
```

I know that using tuples instead to ensure that the number of elements matches works when performing multiple assignment (e.g., `val (a, b) = ("c", "d")`), but you cannot map over tuples (which makes sense because they have heterogeneous types).

I also know I can just define my own types for sequence of 2 elements and sequence of 3 elements or whatever, but is there a convenient built in way of doing this? If not, what's the simplest way to define a type that is a sequence of a specific number of elements?

Comment: [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) provides a `Sized` collection whose type tracks the length of the sequence. The extractor currently doesn't enforce the length, though—I have [a pull request](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/93) in for that, and it's likely it'll show up in some form in a future version.